# JWE (JSON Web Encryption) in NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, jwt, jwe, jwk, jose

I am trying to implement JWE for my Rest API. I came across following NODE library that implements JWE. However the library lack the documentation around how JSON Web Key(JWK) should be used(JSON object) that help in Key Management Mode. The [JWE documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#page-5) reads as follows:

*A method of determining the Content Encryption Key value to use.
Each algorithm used for determining the CEK value uses a specific
Key Management Mode.  Key Management Modes employed by this
specification are Key Encryption, Key Wrapping, Direct Key
Agreement, Key Agreement with Key Wrapping, and Direct Encryption.*

So I want to know how I should feed the JWK to this library inorder to implement JWE ? **I want to know how my JSON format will dictate the Key Managemnet Mode** ?
Can any one provide mi such JSON format for JWK and tell how that provide the Key Management Mode ?

[Node-jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jose)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a documentation for my PHP framework where you will find [a table about the relationship](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/advanced-topics-1/encrypted-tokens-and/multiple-recipients) between the encryption algorithm and the key management mode.